# QSettings - Sync issue between two process

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, pyqt

I am using Qsettings for non gui products to store its settings into xml files. This is written as a library which gets used in C, C++ programs. There will be 1 xml file file for each product. Each product might have more than one sub products and they are written into xml by subproduct grouping as follows -

**File: "product1.xml"**

```
<product1>
    <subproduct1>
       <settings1>..</settings1>
       ....
       <settingsn>..</settingsn>
    </subproduct1>
    ...
    <subproductn>
       <settings1>..</settings1>
       ....
       <settingsn>..</settingsn>
    </subproductn>

 </product1>
```

**File: productn.xml**

```
<productn>
   <subproduct1>
       <settings1>..</settings1>
       ....
       <settingsn>..</settingsn>
   </subproduct1>
   ...
   <subproductn>
       <settings1>..</settings1>
       ....
       <settingsn>..</settingsn>
   </subproductn>

 </productn>
```

The code in one process does the following -

```
settings = new QSettings("product1.xml", XmlFormat);
settings.setValue("settings1",<value>)
sleep(20);
settings.setValue("settings2", <value2>)
settings.sync();
```

When the first process goes to sleep, I start another process which does the following -

```
settings = new QSettings("product1.xml", XmlFormat);
settings.remove("settings1")
settings.setValue("settings3", <value3>)
settings.sync();
```

I would expect the settings1 to go away from product1.xml file but it still persist in the file - product1.xml at the end of above two process. I am not using QCoreApplication(..) in my settings library. Please point issues if there is anything wrong in the above design.

Comment: Does the "settings3" line execute?

Comment: Just curious, did you write the XML parsers for QSettings yourself? I was looking for a working version which works with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an odd thing that you're doing, but one thing to note is that the sync() call is what actually writes the file to disk. In this case if you want your second process to actually see the changes you've made, then you'll need to call sync() **before** your second process accesses the file in order to guarantee that it will actually see your modifications.  Thus I would try putting a `settings.sync()` call right before your `sleep(20)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to do `delete settings;` after the `sync()` to make sure it is not open, then do the writing in the other process?

Answer (score 0):

Does this compile? What implementation of XmlFormat are you using and which OS? There must be some special code in your project for storing / reading to and from Xml - there must be something in this code which works differently from what you expect.

Comment: I am registering my custom xmlreader and xmlwriter to handle xml stuff.     const QSettings::Format XmlFormat = 
  QSettings::registerFormat("xml", readXmlFile, writeXmlFile);

Comment: Probably, your problems arise from the way, you open your file and the issue Chris mentions. Examine the code of your xmlReader/Writer for the way, files are opened.